# método Radix-sort não funciona corretamente!

Tags: c, c++

**[.cpp tem q medir e e fazer a média do tempo de processamento dos métodos de implementação]**

Após implementar o Radix todos pararam de cronometrar o tempo corretamente.

*O programa perguntas quantos números e quantas execuções, ele só executa 1x no radix.*

**Possível local do erro entre as linhas 161-197** *(local onde esta o radix)*

link para ver o funcionamento: https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/rkRmSLk24

**Parte onde é possivel estar o erro** *(linhas 161-197)*

```
int getMax(int v[], int tam)
{
    int max = v[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < tam; i++)
        if (v[i] > max)
            max = v[i];
    return max;
}

void countSort(int v[], int tam, int exp)
{
    int output[tam], i, count[10] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        count[(v[i] / exp) % 10]++;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i-1];

    for (i = tam - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[(v[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = v[i];
        count[(v[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        v[i] = output[i];
}

void radixsort(int v[], int tam)
{
    int exp, m;
    m = getMax(v, tam);

    for (exp = 1; m/exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        countSort(v, tam, exp);
}
```

**código completo** *(código todo comentado e de fácil localização das implementações)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *v, *v1, *v2, *v3, *v4, *v5, *v6, *v7;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void bubbleSort(int v[], int n)
{
    bool trocou;
    int k = n;

    do {
      trocou = false;
      k--;
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        if (v[i+1] < v[i]) {
          int aux = v[i+1];
          v[i+1] = v[i];
          v[i] = aux;
          trocou = true;
        }
    } while (trocou);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void insertionSort(int v[], int n)
{
    int i, j, chave;
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        chave = v[j];
        i = j - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && v[i] > chave) {
            v[i+1] = v[i];
            i--;
        }
        v[i+1] = chave;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void selectionSort(int v[], int n)
{
  int i, j, min;

  for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
      if (v[j] < v[min])
        min = j;

    if (min != i) {
      int temp = v[min];
      v[min] = v[i];
      v[i] = temp;
    }
  }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void shellSort(int v[], int n)
{
    int i , j , valor;
    int h = 1;
    while(h < n) {
        h = 3*h+1;
    }
    while (h > 1) {
        h /= 3;
        for(i = h; i < n; i++) {
            valor = v[i];
            j = i - h;
            while (j >= 0 && valor < v[j]) {
                v [j + h] = v[j];
                j -= h;
            }
            v [j + h] = valor;
        }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void quickSort1(int v[], int ini, int fim)
{
    int i = ini;
    int j = fim;
    int pivo = v[(ini+ fim)/2];  // Pivo e o elemento central

    do
    {
        while (v[i] < pivo && i < fim)
            i++;
        while (pivo < v[j] && j > ini)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            int aux = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = aux;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (ini < j)
        quickSort1(v,ini,j);
    if (i < fim)
        quickSort1(v,i,fim);
}

void quickSort(int v[], int tam)
{
    quickSort1(v, 0, tam-1);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void intercala(int v[], int aux[], int ini, int meio, int fim)
{
    int i = ini, j = fim, k;

    for (k = ini; k <= meio; k++)
        aux[k] = v[k];

    for (k = meio+1; k <= fim; k++)
        aux[fim + meio + 1 - k] = v[k];

    for (k = ini; k <= fim; k++)
        if (aux[i] <= aux[j])
            v[k] = aux[i++];
        else
            v[k] = aux[j--];
}

void mergeSort1(int v[], int aux[], int ini, int fim)
{
    if (ini < fim) {
        int meio = (ini + fim) / 2;
        mergeSort1(v, aux, ini, meio);
        mergeSort1(v, aux, meio+1, fim);
        intercala(v, aux, ini, meio, fim);
    }
}

void mergeSort(int v[], int n)
{
    int *aux = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    mergeSort1(v, aux, 0, n-1);

    free(aux);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int getMax(int v[], int tam)
{
    int max = v[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < tam; i++)
        if (v[i] > max)
            max = v[i];
    return max;
}

void countSort(int v[], int tam, int exp)
{
    int output[tam], i, count[10] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        count[(v[i] / exp) % 10]++;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i-1];

    for (i = tam - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[(v[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = v[i];
        count[(v[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        v[i] = output[i];
}

void radixsort(int v[], int tam)
{
    int exp, m;
    m = getMax(v, tam);

    for (exp = 1; m/exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        countSort(v, tam, exp);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gerar(int v[], int tam)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        v[i] = rand() % 100000001;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void copiar(int origem[], int destino[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        destino[i] = origem[i];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool verifica(int v[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        if (v[i] > v[i+1])
            return false;

    return true;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void inverte(int v[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = n-1; i < n/2; i++,j--)
        v[i] = v[j];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, end;
    long double cpu_time;
    int tam, iter;
    char metodos[100];
    long double tempo[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    tam = 0;
    printf("Quantos numeros? ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    getchar();

    if (tam <= 0)
        return 0;

    printf("Selecione os metodos:\n  1-Bubble sort\n  2-Selection sort\n  3-Insertion sort\n  4-Shell sort\n  5-Quicksort\n  6-Mergesort\n  7-Radix sort\nMetodos: ");
    gets(metodos);

    printf("Quantas execucoes (1, 2, 3, ...)? ");
    scanf("%d", &iter);
    getchar();

    if (iter <= 0)
        return 0;

    v  = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v1 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v2 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v3 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v4 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v5 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v6 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    v7 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 1; i <= iter; i++) {
        printf("------------------------------------------------\nExecucao %d:\n------------------------------------------------\n", i);

        printf("Gerando %d elementos...\n", tam);
        gerar(v, tam);
        copiar(v, v1, tam);
        copiar(v, v2, tam);
        copiar(v, v3, tam);
        copiar(v, v4, tam);
        copiar(v, v5, tam);
        copiar(v, v6, tam);
        copiar(v, v7, tam);

        // bubble
        if (strchr(metodos, '1') != NULL) {
            printf("Bubble sort...\n");

            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            bubbleSort(v1, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v1, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[0] += cpu_time;
        }

        // selection
        if (strchr(metodos, '2') != NULL) {
            printf("Selection sort...\n");
            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            selectionSort(v3, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v3, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[1] += cpu_time;
        }

        // insertion
        if (strchr(metodos, '3') != NULL) {
            printf("Insertion sort...\n");

            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            insertionSort(v2, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v2, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[2] += cpu_time;
        }


        // shell
        if (strchr(metodos, '4') != NULL) {
            printf("Shell sort...\n");

            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            shellSort(v4, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v4, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[3] += cpu_time;
        }

        // quick
        if (strchr(metodos, '5') != NULL) {
            printf("Quick sort...\n");

            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            quickSort(v5, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v5, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[4] += cpu_time;
        }

        // merge
        if (strchr(metodos, '6') != NULL) {
            printf("Merge sort...\n");

            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            mergeSort(v6, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v6, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[5] += cpu_time;
        }

        //radixsort
        if (strchr(metodos, '7') != NULL) {
            printf("Radix sort...\n");

            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            radixsort(v7, tam);

            end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

            cpu_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() / (long double) 1000000.0;

            printf("%s. Tempo: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", verifica(v7, tam) ? "OK":"ERRO", cpu_time, cpu_time/1000);

            tempo[6] += cpu_time;
        }
    }

    if (iter > 1) {
        printf("-------------------------------------------\nTempos medios:\n");
        if (strchr(metodos, '1') != NULL)
            printf("Bubble sort:    %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[0]/iter, tempo[0]/(iter*1000));
        if (strchr(metodos, '2') != NULL)
            printf("selection sort: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[1]/iter, tempo[1]/(iter*1000));
        if (strchr(metodos, '3') != NULL)
            printf("Insertion sort: %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[2]/iter, tempo[2]/(iter*1000));
        if (strchr(metodos, '4') != NULL)
            printf("Shell sort:     %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[3]/iter, tempo[3]/(iter*1000));
        if (strchr(metodos, '5') != NULL)
            printf("Quick sort:     %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[4]/iter, tempo[4]/(iter*1000));
        if (strchr(metodos, '6') != NULL)
            printf("Merge sort:     %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[5]/iter, tempo[5]/(iter*1000));
        if (strchr(metodos, '7') != NULL)
            printf("Radix sort:     %lf ms (%lf s)\n", tempo[6]/iter, tempo[6]/(iter*1000));
    }

    free(v);
    free(v1);
    free(v2);
    free(v3);
    free(v4);
    free(v5);
    free(v6);
    free(v7);
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema com implementação do Radix sort](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382023/problema-com-implementa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-radix-sort)

Comment: Por favor não duplique perguntas. Se a [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/382023/112052) não foi bem recebida, vc deve **editá-la** e corrigir os problemas (inclusive tem vários comentários lá explicando o que/como arrumar).

Comment: arrumei e a deixei na forma q pediram, por isso criei uma outra

Comment: Mesmo que vc tenha apagado a pergunta anterior, esta aqui está praticamente idêntica, e portanto com os mesmos problemas já apontados... Se vai postar novamente, pelo menos tente seguir as orientações que foram dadas anteriormente (como por exemplo reduzir o código para um [mcve])

Comment: Talvez na primeira vez que ele chegue na Terra o Goku já mate ele com ajuda do Piccolo

Answer (score 0):

Não verifiquei nenhum erro no seu método `radixsort()` e como o intervalo de duração é calculado separadamente para cada uma das funções invocadas, não consigo imaginar como a implementação desse método em particular poderia impactar no output do programa quando outros métodos são invocados.

De todo o modo, eu testei o seu programa no CodeBlocks (SO Windows 10) e, curiosamente, ele funcionou, informando corretamente o intervalo da execução de cada método de sorting. Então fui verificar o que havia de errado com o ambiente que você deixou o link. Inseri o seguinte código na área da `main()` reservada para o método Buble Sort:

```
//verifica e imprime time_clock armazenado na variável start
auto st = start.time_since_epoch();
 int startInt = std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(st).count();
 std::cout << "start == " << startInt << std::endl;

//verifica e imprime time_clock armazenado na variável end
 auto en = end.time_since_epoch();
 int endInt = std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(en).count();
 std::cout << "end == " << endInt << std::endl;
//[...]
//imprime valor armazenado na varíavel cpu_time
std::cout << "cpu time == " << cpu_time << std::endl;
```

O output do programa, escolhendo-se a opção 10.000 números com Buble Sort, foi:

```
Gerando 10000 elementos...                                                                                            
Bubble sort...                                                                                                        
start == 21427696                                                                                                     
end == 644719493                                                                                                      
cpu time == 623.292                                                                                                   
OK. Tempo: 0.000000 ms (0.000000 s)
```

Com base nesse resultado, me parece claro que o programa, na implementação que você indicou, calcula e armazena corretamente o intervalo de tempo. Portanto, imagino que o erro esteja ocorrendo no output desse valor, ou seja, na função `printf()`

Por sorte, quando eu estava inserindo o código para debug, eu cometi um erro de sintaxe e o interpretador, além de indicar o meu erro de síntaxe, informou o seguinte aviso:

```
main.cpp:821:16: warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'long double' [-Wformat=]
main.cpp:864:16: warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'long double' [-Wformat=]
 cpu_time / 1000);
```

O aviso se repete para as outras vezes que o `printf()` é invocado.

Por fim, talvez, você esteja se perguntando: e como corrigir isso?, em outras palavras, qual o formato adequado para `printf()` imprimir um `long double`? Essa questão é problemática, porque algumas implementações não tem suporte para `long double`, para mais detalhes dê uma olhada nessa questão: [printf and long double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double).

Então, o jeito mais fácil seria simplesmente substituir a variável `long double cpu_time` por `double cpu_time`. Fiz isso no link que você passou e o seu programa funcionou como o esperado.